# Not able to find the DPI for an image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, dpi

I want to find the DPI for an image that has been captured from iPhone/iPad Camera

this is how i am trying to get the DPI

```
 CFDictionaryRef exifDict = CMGetAttachment(imageDataSampleBuffer,
                                            kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary ,
                                            NULL);
originalExifDict = (__bridge NSMutableDictionary *)(exifDict);
[originalExifDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight]
[originalExifDict objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth]
```

However both the entries in the dictionary come to be 0.
What is the correct way to find the DPI ? 
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Image DPI are more of a display property and arbitrary, they can be changed at will without any change to the image. A camera itself does not have a DPI, just the image size in pixels.

Comment: why are not you calculating the `DPI` for your own, if that is not available? If you know the physical area where you'd like to print the picture, the `DPI` can be calculated via a very simple formula; or vica verse if you know the image size in pixels and the `DPI` the physical area can be calculated from them.

Comment: After some reading i have concluded that DPI does not have any meaning for digital images.Instead Pixels Per inch can be calculated. Even if iOS gives the value for DPI it will be basically meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CGSize size;     
    NSNumber *width = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(exifDict, kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth);
    NSNumber *height = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(exifDict, kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight);
    size.width = [width floatValue];
    size.height = [height floatValue];
```

//Tell me its work or not.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer I tried this way  but still i am getting 0 for both width and height. Other entries in the exif dictionary like aperture value and exposure mode are coming correct.

Answer (score 0):

The information isn't in the metadata that comes with your `imageDataSampleBuffer`. It is written (72 dpi) at the time the image is saved, *unless* you have, first, manually set it yourself when editing the metadata, before the save.

For most purposes, it *is* meaningless, However, some software uses it to calculate the "correct size" of an image when placing it in a document. A 3000 pixel square image at 300 dpi will thus appear 10 inches (c.25.4 cm) square; at 72 dpi it will be nearly 42 inches (c.105.8 cm) square. Also, some online image uploaders (especially those used by stock photo libraries and the like) insist on images having high-ish dpi.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using imagePickerController use this below code

```
NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:assetURL
         resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)  {
             NSMutableDictionary *imageMetadata = nil;
             NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
             imageMetadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:metadata];
             NSLog (@"imageMetaData from AssetLibrary %@",imageMetadata);

             NSString *dpi = [imageMetadata objectForKey:@"DPIHeight"];

             NSLog (@"Dpi: %@",dpi);

         }
        failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog (@"error %@",error);
        }];
```